# Can I install a bidet seat/washlet without a tank?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

I'm interested in adding a washlet to my toilet seat (like this one for example https://www.brondell.com/swash-300-bidet-toilet-seat/) but I'm not sure if I can do so given that my toilet doesn't have a water tank above it.

Here is a photo of where the toilet connects to the wall:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The bidets use a T which is installed between the water supply to the toilet and the fill value on the tank.  You have neither the fill valve or the typical toilet water supply.

You should be able to go from the hose bib with the red handle to a 3/8" female adapter that would then allow the bidet supply to connect.

Comment: @user1475412 be aware that the hose that goes from the T-connector to the bidet might have an odd thread that you could have trouble adapting.  You'll have to look at it when it comes in, but it might be easier to use the T-connector and cap off the top rather than trying to adapt to the bidet hose directly.

Comment: Good point about the bidet supply connector.  I've installed a couple and they both seemed to use the 3/8".  I suppose if they didn't then you could cap the T connector though the female connector to the fill valve would be tricky.  You'd need a 7/8" IPS threaded nipple and cap ( I am not sure how available those would be though you could get them made up at a machine shop ).